# How to maintain repositories into a single repository

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have a repository for each micro-services ('A', 'B', ..). The structure of a repository looks like :

```
A
|-dockerfile
|-src
  |-Java
  |-Groovy
```

Since all of these repositories belongs to a project called 'WholeProject', I want to maintain a repository 'WholeProject' which looks like :

```
WholeProject
|-docker-compose.yml
|-µS
  |-A
  |-B
  |-..
```

So I could easily maintain a docker-compose file and a repository that contains all the revelant things about my project.

Is this a good idea ? How can I perform that ?

Comment: [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) with:

```
cd /path/to/WholeProject
git submodule -- /url/to/repo/A µS/A
git submodule -- /url/to/repo/B µS/B
```

That way, you can clone WholeProject with a:

```
git clone --recursive
```

And you get `A` and `B` at their last recorded SHA1.

Comment: Thanks ! That works and that answer my question. But I'm wondering if it is a good idea or if there is another better strategy to apply.. ?

Comment: @DouglasAdams The alternative, if you want a monorepo, is subtree: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/ https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/ (but if A and B have different lifecycles, that is different branches and tags, submodules are a better fit)